# JList custom renderer and HTML

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I would like to make an JListh which will present my html code in their cells so I do:

```
public class HtmlCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public static final int CONST_PREFERED_HEIGHT = 200;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus) {
        JLabel label = (JLabel) super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, hasFocus);
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 50, CONST_PREFERED_HEIGHT ));
        if (value != null) {
            ExtendedJEditorPane htmlPane = new ExtendedJEditorPane();
            label.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            htmlPane.setEditable(false);
            htmlPane.setContentType("text/html" );
            htmlPane.setText(value.toString());
            label.add(htmlPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

        return label;
    }
}
```

for a custom renderer. Here I make a new JEditPane ( I extend it in order to draw some custom tags in my html) and insert it to the cell's label but the result is that my cell does not recognize the html and print the raw text instead.

The input text is:

```
"<table><tr><td rowspan=\"2\"><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"+myImageData+\" align=\"left\" /></td><td><h3>Test1 </h3><hr></td></tr><tr><td><p>Test</td></tr></table>"
```

The list entry object will return this string in case of toString execution.

Comment: *"Do you have any idea?"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( 50, CONST_PREFERED_HEIGHT ));`  If using HTML in a styled `JComponent`, it makes just as much sense (or nonsense, depending on how you view it) to set the size of the component within styles in the HTML.  Even better, you can set one of the width or height, and have the other adjust as per need of content.

Comment: unrelated: a) do not create components in getXXRendererComponent, instead create in constructor and re-use b) do not mis-use JLabel as a container, instead implement a renderer which either vends the component directly or a general purpose container (JPanel) containing the component c) do not hard-code sizing hints

Comment: kleopatra: Thanks just did it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
return label;
```

Try using this:

```
return htmlPane;
```

Comment: Now the Jlist draws the html code but it does not working properly so I cant select my cell. I guess that normally I must return the Label because it is already registered inside JList, or find the way to replace this Label.

Comment: *"I guess.."*  Stop guessing & post an SSCCE.  Then I can give you better answers than 'try this'.